# How to add listener for a custom event in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

What I want is to create my own function that will be bound as an event listener similar to how other event listeners (e.g., `onclick`) are set:

```html
<input type="text" onMyFunction="alert('hi');" />
```

Is it possible and if so how?

Comment: You want to listen to / trigger an Event of custom type? What do you mean with "permanently called"?

Comment: how would you fire this event?

Comment: It sound like you should describe the problem more in terms of what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: It's like `onFastScroll="stopScroll();"` and after I write the function `onFastScroll` to detect if the scroll is fast. (Instead of doing `setInterval(onFastScroll,0);`)

Comment: How is the scrolling related to the input element?

Comment: you can bind anything to an element, but the real question is how this event gets fired via the input? how does scrolling get fired from the input anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is the browser does not realize it is a function in there. It is a string, the only way you can make it a function is to assign it as a function.

One way is either on document ready or onload, you query the document for elements with the attribute and reassign it.

**HTML**

```
<input id="foo1" type="text" onMyFunction="alert(this.value);" value="1"/>
<input id="foo2" type="text" onMyFunction="alert(this.value);" value="2"/>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
var winLoad = window.onload;
window.onload = function(){
    var i, 
        elem,
        fncStr,    
        elems = document.querySelectorAll("[onMyFunction]");

    if (winLoad) {
        winLoad();
    }

    for (i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {
        elem = elems[i];
        fncStr = elem.getAttribute("onMyFunction");
        elem.onMyFunction = new Function(fncStr);        
    }

    var tb1 = document.getElementById("foo1");
    tb1.onMyFunction();​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
}
```

[Example running here](http://jsfiddle.net/jgpV8/)

This code uses [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) which is not supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using pure JavaScript, but jQuery is simpler:

```
<input id="someId" type="text" />

$('#someId').bind('myCustomEvent', function(event) {
  alert('hi');
});
```

And to trigger it elsewhere in the code:

```
$("#someId").trigger('myCustomEvent');
```

More info here: http://dailyjs.com/2009/11/14/jquery-custom-events/

Comment: Love how a question not tagged jQuery gets an accepted answer with jQuery. lol

Comment: @user1365010 It is a library that not everyone uses. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this right, you want to have something happen when your javascript function is called. Why not just put what you want to happen in your actual function?

```
<script type="javascript/text">
function MyFunction(){
// some code
alert('hi');
</script>
```

I'm not sure what you mean by permanently called, but in the code above an alert that displays hi will happen every time your function is called, similar to what you described in your question, but using a different implementation.

As far as actually using onMyFunction="alert('hi')", I don't believe this is possible because the onClick, onload, and onmouseover events are built in. So unless you write extra code that implements onMyFunction correctly, I don't see a way to do it.